# React app converted to react-native - problem with react-redux and react-thunk

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I converted this application
https://codesandbox.io/s/3y77o7vnkp `<--Please check this link`
into my react-native app and it works perfect. Since I implemented redux and redux-thunk I have a problem with fetching data.

There is a problem. I converted normal functions from this upper link to actions and reducers in react-native. For Example

```
handleSelect = itemValue => {
    this.setState(
      {
        ...this.state,
        base: itemValue,
        result: null,
      },
      this.calculate
    );
  };
```

TO
actiontypes.js

`export const HANDLE_FIRST_SELECT = 'HANDLE_FIRST_SELECT';`

action.js

```
export const handleFirstSelect = itemValue => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.HANDLE_FIRST_SELECT,
    itemValue: itemValue,
  };
};
```

and reducer.js

```
const initialState = {
  currencies: ['USD', 'AUD', 'SGD', 'PHP', 'EUR', 'PLN', 'GBP'],
  base: 'EUR',
  amount: '',
  convertTo: 'PLN',
  result: '',
  date: '',
  error: null,
  loading: false,
};
 const exchangeCurrencies = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.HANDLE_FIRST_SELECT:
      return {
        ...state,
        base: action.itemValue,
        result: null,
      };
...
```

Next step I used mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps in my component like this

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    handleFirstSelect: itemValue =>
      dispatch(exchangeCurriencesActions.handleFirstSelect(itemValue)),
...

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    base: state.base,
    amount: state.amount,
    convertTo: state.convertTo,
    result: state.result,
    date: state.date,
  };
};
```

And I'm using now this.props

```
<PickerComponent
    selectedValue={this.props.base}
    onValueChange={this.props.handleFirstSelect}
/>
```

Until then, everything works ok. Now when I download data in this way with react-redux and redux-thunk (action.js) it stops working

```
export const fetchDataSuccess = data => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS,
    data: data,
  };
};

export const fetchDataFail = error => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.FETCH_DATA_FAIL,
    error: error,
  };
};

export const fetchData = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    fetch(`https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=${this.props.base}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        data => dispatch(fetchDataSuccess(data.rates)),
        e => dispatch(fetchDataFail(e)),
      );
  };
};
```

next reducer.js

```
...
case actionTypes.FETCH_DATA_BEGIN:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
        error: null,
      };
    case actionTypes.FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS:
      console.log('data', action.data);
      return {
        ...state,
        date: action.data.date,
        result: action.data.rates,
        loading: false,
      };
    case actionTypes.FETCH_DATA_FAIL:
      console.log('data', action.error);
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        error: action.error,
      };
...
```

In the next step added function fetchData into mapDispatchToProps and call this in componentDidMount like that

```
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.amount === isNaN) {
      return;
    } else {
      try {
        this.props.fetchData();
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('error', e);
      }
    }
  }
```

and finnaly I add calculations for currencies in mapStateToProps. I change result like that
 `result: (state.result[state.convertTo] * state.amount).toFixed(4),`

and also I added applymiddleware into the store.

AND FINNALY THERE IS A ERROR

[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import HomeContentContainer from '../../containers/HomeContentContainer/HomeContentContainer';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <HomeContentContainer />;
  }
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

Anyone know how to resolve this problem? Where and what should I change the code?

Comment: I can't say definitively since the error line (`at HomeScreen.js line 6`) is not actually in the code you posted, but it definitely has something to do with `result: (state.result[state.convertTo] * state.amount).toFixed(4),`.  You are trying to access a property on `state.result` which is initialized as a string `...result: '',` in map state to props.

Comment: I added HomeScreen.js into my post

Comment: I would say most likely data.rates which you get back from the API is not being set....

Comment: Mind you I checked the API call and it does return an object with rates...

Comment: OHH, you know whats happening.  The map state to props is being called as you would expect when you make the request before the data has come back, so the error occurs before result is even set!  Add some code to check result being set and if null or has no properties map somthing else, otherwise do your function.

Comment: So as Henry was alluding to, the other option would be to initislise result to a proper object which works with your map state to props function, then when the data comes back it will be called again with your data... but mixing types is going to result in issues like this. you are going from a string to complex object....if you used typescript it would never allow this unless you were explicit!

Comment: can u show code how to do it Michael?

Answer (score 0):

Following up on the comments to the question, please do review those...

In `mapStateToProps` protect your access to `state.result`, like this perhaps:

`result: state.result ? (state.result[state.convertTo] * state.amount).toFixed(4) : null`

, where `null` could also be `0` or whatever, your call.  Your `mapStateToProps` is indeed getting called (at least) once before the API request is completed, so it needs to handle your initial state of `state.result`.

I find it confusing that the components property `result` and the `state.result` are different things, but this is just my opinion about naming.